# Building a project with log4j using maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, log4j, slf4j

I have a maven project in which I am using slf4j.log4j. When I run my project in the IDE it runs fine and shows the log on the console.

But when I pack the project as a jar and run it I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at com.hl7.common.StartListeners.<clinit>(StartListeners.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hl7</groupId>
  <artifactId>appointments-web</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is my log4j.properties file in `src/main/resources`

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, consoleAppender, fileAppender

log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=HL7.log
```

Here is how I use the logger -

```
package com.hl7.common;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class StartListeners {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartListeners.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ListenersManager.start();
        logger.info("Listeners started.....................");
        return;
    }
```

How can I build my project using maven so that the dependencies are included in the jar. I have read a lot of answers but I am getting more confused the more I read. Please tell what all changes I need to make to the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pack your project as a jar, the Maven dependencies are not included. Add all maven dependencies when you run the program from the console or build a "big jar". http://orphanware.blogspot.de/2010/09/creating-fat-jar-using-maven.html